# How can I make a list of lists

Tags: c#

I'm trying to store a set of lists in a list but because forces the programmer in <> what data type the list is going to hold and also the list which the list contains I seem to be unable to add my lists to my master list containing list without getting an error telling me I am not adding the correct type of list.

```
public List<MyObject1> List1{ get; set; }
public List<MyObject2> List2{ get; set; }
List<List<object>> myMasterList; //nested type definitions here

public SetUpLists()
{
    List1= new List<MyObject1>();
    List2= new List<MyObject2>();
    myMasterList= new List<List<object>>(); //nested type definitions here

    //ERROR ON NEXT 2 LINES
    'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<object>>.Add(System.Collections.Generic.List<object>)' has some invalid arguments.

    myMasterList.Add(List1);
    upgradeList.Add(List2);
}
```

So from looking at the error report it seems like it should be working. I've even tried making it so its not `List<List<object>>` but a parent class on the `MyObject1` and `MyObject2` classes: `List<List<MyObjectMaster>>` - to no avail I get the same error.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: how about Dictionary<int, List<whatever>>?

Comment: @cookieMonster: The problem is that there's no single type which can be used for `whatever`.  `List<T>` is invariant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

myMasterList is typed as a `List<List<object>>`, which will only accept `List<object>` type elements.  While MyObject1 is derived from object, `List<MyObject1>` is not equivalent to `List<object>`.

To get around this, you can either use myMasterList as a `List<object>` and cast the objects to `List<object>` each time you access them, or use a Linq query like this to cast your individual lists to `List<object>` before inserting them.

```
myMasterList.Add(List1.Select(item => item as Object).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

`List1` is of type `List<MyObject1>` but you are using it as it were `List<object>`. These may look similar but are not the same and are not convertible.

Your solution here is to make lists of a common base type or inteface of `MyObject1` and `MyObject2`. If nothing else, you may use `List<object>` everywhere.

You say that you tried with `MyObjectMaster`, but you didn't show the code... the issue is probably that `List<MyObjectMaster>` and `List<MyObject1>` are not convertible either... That is, you should use exactly the same type of list everywhere.